# can't use fixed value in default function in Mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

im trying to calculate `SSC` which is calculated by multiplying `basicSalary` by `0.07%`, in `totalEarnings`, `totalDeductions` and `netSalary` it works fine by doing calculations on fields, but in `SSC` multiplying `basicSalary` by `0.07%` gives an error `expression expected`, does that i mean i only can use fields ?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const salariesSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  basicSalary: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
  accomodation: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  transportation: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  bonus: { type: Number, default: 0 },

  SSC: { type: Number, default: function(){
    return this.basicSalary * 0.07%
  } },

  incomeTax: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  medicalInsurance: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  loan: { type: Number, default: 0, default: null },

  totalEarnings: {
    type: Number,
    default: function () {
      return (
        this.basicSalary + this.accomodation + this.transportation + this.bonus
      );
    },
  },

  totalDeductions: {
    type: Number,
    defualt: function () {
      return this.SSC - this.incomeTax - this.medicalInsurance - this.loan;
    },
  },

  netSalary: {
    type: Number,
    default: function () {
      return this.totalEarnings - this.totalDeductions;
    },
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("salarie", salariesSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate the 7% of the value you should write:

```
SSC: { 
    type: Number, 
    default: function () {
        return this.basicSalary * 0.07;
    } 
}
```

Comment: LOL, i will just accept your answer and lets act like its a good question